# Object.prototype.function is not a function Javascript

Tags: javascript, function, prototype

I'm sure this is a common question, but I am completely at a lack for why this is not working.

```js
function WorleyNoise2D(numPoints, width, height, seed, type) {
    this._numPoints = numPoints || 1;
    this._keyPoints = {};
    this._getKeyPoints();
    
    return this._keyPoints;
}


WorleyNoise2D.prototype._getKeyPoints = function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < this._numPoints; i++) {
        this._keyPoints.push({
            x: Math.random(),
            y: Math.random()
        });
    }
};

(function () {
    console.log(WorleyNoise2D(10));
})();
```

It keeps returning that the prototype is not a function.

*** UPDATE *** figured it out after I started thinking about what you guys were saying!

```js
function WorleyNoise2D(numPoints, width, height, seed, type) {
  this._numPoints = numPoints || 1;
  this._keyPoints = {};
}


WorleyNoise2D.prototype._getKeyPoints = function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < this._numPoints; i++) {
    this._keyPoints[i] = {
      x: Math.random(),
      y: Math.random()
    };
  }
};



(function() {



  var worly = new WorleyNoise2D();
  worly._numPoints = 10;

  worly._getKeyPoints();

  console.log(JSON.stringify(worly._keyPoints));


})();
```

Comment: You never create an instance with `new`, so there are no inherited properties

Comment: Also note that you can't push to an object

Comment: This function looks like a constructor but attempts to `return this._keyPoints;`. What do you expect this to do?

Comment: @adeneo ok not being able to push to an object aside, can you explain the instance creation to make inherited properties

Comment: https://github.com/zsoltc/worley-noise/blob/master/src/worley-noise.js

in this example he calls _init(); in the same manor, and I have tested that code and it works... what am I doing different?

Comment: @user2472643: You're not using [`new`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new)!